# issue relational operator in vector c++

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stl

today I wrote this code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main(){
   vector <int> a (4,100);
   vector <int> b (1,100);

   cout<<(b<a);
}
```

as the reference says this is true only if if the contents of the b are lexicographically less than the contents of a, false otherwise, but in the output I obtain true, someone can explain me.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_cmp

Comment: And `b` is indeed lexicographically less than `a`.

Comment: Most probably you misinterpreted the meaning of [lexicographically](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order).

Comment: (You can see [`std::lexicographical_compare`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lexicographical_compare) for an explanation of lexicographical comparison rules)

Comment: just curious what do you think `lexicographical order` means?

Comment: `a` contains `{100, 100, 100, 100}` and `b` contains `{100}`. This is like comparing “AAAA” and ”A”—the shorter vector comes first, lexicographically.

Answer (score 2):

From http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lexicographical_compare,

> Lexicographical comparison is a operation with the following properties:
>
> . Two ranges are compared element by element.
>
> . The first mismatching element defines which range is lexicographically less or greater than the other.
>
> . If one range is a prefix of another, the shorter range is lexicographically less than the other.
>
> . If two ranges have equivalent elements and are of the same length, then the ranges are lexicographically equal.
>
> . An empty range is lexicographically less than any non-empty range.
>
> . Two empty ranges are lexicographically equal.

In your case, the third clause applies.

Answer (score 0):

The rules for std::lexicographical_compare which is invoked to handle

```
a < b
```

say that if one range is a prefix of another, the shorter range is lexicographically less than the other.

Here the *range* of **a** refers to the elements from **a**.begin() up to but excluding **a**.end() - in other words all the elements in **a**

Similarly, the *range* of **b** refers to the elements from **b**.begin() up to but excluding **b**.end() - in other words all the elements in **b**

**b** (which holds a single int of value 100) IS a prefix of **a** (which holds 4 integers of value 100) so **b** (the shorter range) is considered less than **a**, hence **b < a** is true.

See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lexicographical_compare for further details.